# Java Convert AudioFormat

Tags: java, audio, audioformat

what I'm trying to do is that I am capturing the audio from microphone via TargetDataLine class, send it with socket and play on another side via SourceDataLine. The problem is that microphone I'm capturing with, only supports:

```
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(48000, 16, 1, true, true);
```

and the speaker I'm playing it to, supports only:

```
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(32000, 16, 2, true, true);
```

When I directly get 48khz and push it to 32khz audioformat, the sound is pitched, is there any way to convert the 48khz mono sound to 32khz stereo?

Answer (score 0):

If Java has some built in audio file format conversion, you can learn about it from the "[Using Files and Format Converters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html)" post on the audio tutorials thread.

If it has to be done manually, check out the first code example on that page, especially noting the point with the comment

> ```
>   // Here, do something useful with the audio data that's 
>   // now in the audioBytes array...
> ```

If you run the input and output lines in parallel, you can use linear interpolation to take data from the 48000 line and post to the 32000 line. The ratio is 3:2.

Thus, for 3 PCM data points in the input, calculate 2 PCM data points for the output.

For the input, you would send in[0] to out[0] and the sum of in[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html)/2 and in[2]/2 to out[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html).

Duplicate the value for converting from mono to stereo.